# Replace JDK 9 with JDK 8

Tags: 14.04, java

I need to replace `JDK 9` with `JDK 8`.

I have installed `JDK 9` using commands:

```
sudo apt-get updatesudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get install oracle-java9-installer
```

How to remove `JDK 9`?

Answer (score 0):

run `sudo apt-get remove oracle-java9-installer`